# Jquery Kendo Grid Footer showing No items to display

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a Asp.Net MVC project and using Jquery kendo in one page to display all users.

index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.User>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

// all script and styles


<div id="grid"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        height: 400,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "Username", title: "User Name" },
            { field: "Password", title: "Password" },
            { field: "LastLogin", title: "LastLogin",
                template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(LastLogin, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #" // date formating
            },  
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: 180 }
        ],
        dataSource: {
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            transport: {
                read: { url: "User_Read" },
                create: { url: "User_Create" },
                update: { url: "User_Update" },
                destroy: { url: "User_Destroy" }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false },
                        Name: { type: "string", validation: { required: true, required: { message: "required" } } },
                        Username: { type: "string", validation: { required: true, required: { message: "required" } } },
                        Password: { type: "string", validation: { required: true, required: { message: "required" } } },
                        LastLogin: { type: "date", validation: { required: true, required: { message: "required" } }, editable: false }
                    }
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            pageSize: 10
        },
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
    });
});
```

Here the read, create, update and destroy functions work well. But the paging is not working.

`pageSize: 10` is working only 10 items are showing but the footer part is not working. I can not change to next page, the buttons are not working and the footer showing no items available.

I searched and found some similiar questions but the answers didnt worked for me.

[image]

This is how the interface looks now. I tried MVC Kendo and it works fine, but my team lead wants jquery kendo. Please help

**UPDATE:**

My controller function for `User_Read`

```
public ActionResult User_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{

    // db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    IQueryable<User> users = db.Users;
    DataSourceResult result = users.ToDataSourceResult(request, usr => new
    {
        Id = usr.Id,
        Name = usr.Name,
        Username = usr.Username,
        Password = usr.Password,
        LastLogin = usr.LastLogin
    });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: How does your controller `User_Read` look like? Your result should contain the total number of items. Are you using `ToDataSourceResult()`, e.g. `Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`? If the total number is missing or zero, the described behavior happens.

Comment: @CarstenFranke I will update the question with the user_read function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @CarstenFranke, in your controller, you should set the total amount of items in the DataSourceResult

```
public ActionResult User_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<User> users = db.Users;
    DataSourceResult result = users.ToDataSourceResult(request, usr => new
    {
        Id = usr.Id,
        Name = usr.Name,
        Username = usr.Username,
        Password = usr.Password,
        LastLogin = usr.LastLogin
    });
    result.Total = users.Count();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In your view, you should also map the total property like:

```
schema: {
    data: "Data",
    model: {...},
    total: "Total"
}
```